# Manipulating a string to combine two or more values into one Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

How would I convert a string such as

```
'1 bag 1 bag 1 bag'
```

to equal

```
'3 bags'
```

Comment: `function convert(string) { return '3 bags'; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "1 bag 1 bag 1 bag"
alert(str.split('bag').length-1  + " bag");
```

if you know what word you look for

Answer (score 1):

With regex `/(\d\s+bag)/g`

```js
var length = '1 bag 1 bag 1 bag 1 bag 1 bag'.match(/(\d\s+bag)/g).length;
console.log(`${length} bags`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not ?

```js
var string='1 bag 1 bag 1 bag 10 bags 1 bag';
var regex=/bags?\s?/;
var res = string.split(regex).reduce((a,i)=> +a+ +i)+" bags";
console.log(res);
```